# UITableView header not displayed with autolayout tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I am using autolayout to add a uitableview to a uiviewcontroller.

In viewDidLoad

```
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[tableView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[tableView|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

I would like to add a tableviewheader in ViewDidLoad

```
UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _tableView.frame.size.width, 200)];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header;
```

But since the tableview is not rendered in viewDidLoad, its width is 0 and thus the header is never displayed.

How can I set the frame of the header so that it will be displayed?

Comment: You should use `viewDidLayoutSubView`. Into viewDidLoad you cant the correct UIViews's frame.

Comment: The header view is displayed, even when setting its frame in viewDidLoad, but it's subviews are not..Any idea why?

Comment: You need to know if your subView has content, ou if it has a correct frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

And

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

to setup the header of the table view.

Comment: It works, but I'd prefer to use tableviewheader to avoid the sticky behavior of section header

Comment: Well then use Grouped style table, not Plain

Comment: Yes that's an option, but can you see any reason why subviews are not displayed when using tableviewheader?

Comment: When do you add them to the header? Is it loaded? Why don't you load the header in the `viewForHeaderInSection` with `Grouped` style and everything should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You can call `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` after you added the constraints. After this, the frame of the `tableView` should be the right one so creating the `headerView` frame should work.

If you have subviews in the `headerView`, they should also have constraints, not static frames.

Let me know how it goes or if you need more help.